# ASP.NET MVC Read files from server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 3 questions:

1. Where is the correct place to put some template files? I'll be using these templates to render emails with [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/). I'm thinking about just having it at `~/Templates/`.
2. How do I unit test this? Should I even unit test reading files from the file system?
3. Best way to read the file into a string?

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-Read-a-Text-File-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I would make a views folder for them `/Views/Emails` perhaps
2. Unit test code that you write, not code from the .NET framework imo
3. `string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( path );`

Comment: @Lol Just provide sample files as assets available to the test. If you have a "test project", put the files there.

Comment: why a views subfolder? and what do you mean unit test code you write and not from the .NET framework...can't understand or infer what you're saying there specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this blog entry, which talks about how to send emails using a view as a template: [ASP.NET MVC 2 Render Template to String](http://www.joeyb.org/blog/2010/01/23/aspnet-mvc-2-render-template-to-string).

In short, you create a method that renders the View into a string and then call that method from an action to generate the email body content.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the code in ~/Content/Templates/ and downloading the content using a web client worked best for me.

```
var welcomeMailTemplatePath = "yourPath";
var webClient = new WebClient();
string html = webClient.DownloadString(WelcomeMailTemplatePath);
```

This way, you don't need to deal with controllers/views and can directly grab the contents of the template file.